# Class Not Being Called Swift iOS

Tags: xcode, macos, class, swift

I'm working on my first app for OSX 10.8 using Swift.  I want to be able to have the state of the battery dictate the text in Today pulldown menu.  That aspect of the code works, but I am very frustrated as my class never gets called.  It is in a separate supporting script called 'DeviceMonitor.swift'.  Thanks for the help!
Code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class BatteryState {

    var device: UIDevice

    init() {
        self.device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
        println("Device Initialized")
    }

    func isPluggedIn(value: Bool) {
        let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.WidgetExtension")

        let batteryState = self.device.batteryState

        if (batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.Charging || batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.Full){
            let isPluggedIn = true
            println("Plugged In")
            sharedDefaults?.setObject("Plugged In", forKey: "stringKey")
        }

        else {
            let isPluggedIn = false
            println("Not Plugged In")
            sharedDefaults?.setObject("Not Plugged In", forKey: "stringKey")
        }
        sharedDefaults?.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have done it somewhere else in your code, it looks like you haven't registered to receive `UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification` events. You should also ensure that the current `UIDevice` has `batteryMonitoringEnabled` as `YES`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I added "var batteryMonitoringEnabled: Bool" and "batteryMonitoringEnabled = true" to the ViewControlled.swift in function ViewDid Load.  I found this code on the Apple website.  However, this did not help.  Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: No, this is a property of `UIDevice`. Example: `UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true`.

Comment: Thanks.  I added this to my code.  My current problem is that this script is never being called (even the initializing "init" doesn't print anything).  How can I solve this?

Comment: jk i was messing around with it and i simply had to call the class with "BatteryState()".  Thanks so much for the help imma noob